# Django 2 multi-table joins?

Tags: django

Python 3.6 / Django 2

I have a Profile model that defines and "extended" `User` model.  I have a Group model that defines some internal, app related groups; and, a ProfileGroupLink model that defines the possible group(s) a profile might belong to.

Let's say the tables look like:

```
    Profile
    ----------
    id              int
    name_last       varchar(32)
    name_first      varchar(32)
    account_number  uuid

    Group
    ----------
    id          uuid
    name        varchar(32)

    ProfileGroupLink
    ----------
    id          int
    groupLnk    uuid    foreign key(Group.id)int
    profileLnk  uuid    foreign key(Profile.account_number)
```

I have the active user "profile" from:

```
my_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

I would normally write an SQL query something like:

```
select Group.name
from Group as Group
inner join Profile as Profile
    on ? = Profile.id
inner join ProfileGroupLink as ProfileGroupLink
    on Profile.id = ProfileGroupLink.profileLnk
    and Group.id = ProfileGroupLink.groupLnk
order by Group.name
```

and pass the profile id in as a parameter.  I am looking at the page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/ but I am not getting the double underscore syntax for joins.

My current attempt is:

```
    groups = Group.objects.all() \
        .filter(GroupList__profile=my_profile.account_number) \
        .filter(GroupList__group=Group__group_id)
```

but PyCharm flags "Group__group_id" as an unresolved reference.  I am importing the models.  How do I do this in Django?

Comment: Your `Group` model has no `GroupList`.  I know you've simplified for here but I think this is wrong

Comment: This is correct.  using the GroupList table I can query all groups based on a profile or all profiles based on a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that what you want to get the query is to obtain the groups that belong to a profile

```
groups = Group.objects.filte(profilegrouplink__profilelnk=my_profile)
```

note that I put everything in lowercase, do not need to put all the joins and do not use the models to make the filters, the attributes are used